# How to run 16 bit code on 32 bit Linux?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, qemu, 16-bit

I have written a small 16-bit assembly program that writes some values in some memory locations.Is there a way I can test it in 32-bit protected mode on Linux?

Comment: what instruction set architecture?  avr? msp430? 8088? 8086? thumb? 16 bit mips?...

Comment: 8086. I was trying to write real mode code.It contains only some movw statements.

Comment: ad pcemu to the list that Yahn provided.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[qemu](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page), [dosbox](http://www.dosbox.com/), [bochs](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Concrete examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22054578/how-to-run-a-program-without-an-operating-system/32483545#32483545

Answer (score 4):

Yes, 16-bit code is supported in user processes in Linux. The system call to do it is called `vm86()` (there's a man page, but there's not much in it). It is, naturally, only works on x86 platforms (and 32-bit only).

If you want an example, the ELKS project has a complete tool for running ELKS 8086 binaries on Linux, which uses it:

https://github.com/lkundrak/dev86/tree/master/elksemu

Look for the `run_elks()` function. It's pretty straightforward.

Comment: Is there any analogous syscall in x86_64?

Comment: @CiroSantilli包子露宪六四事件法轮功 v86 mode isn't supported inside x86-64 native mode. To implement this syscall, Linux would have to switch to 32-bit mode, only then to v86, which would be too much of an overhead for small benefit. But then, there's a [V86-64](http://v86-64.sourceforge.net/) patch (last updated in 2008).